How to Get the Client IP Address in a Next.js Application Hosted on Vercel?
I have a Next.js application hosted on Vercel at example.com. I also have an API hosted at api.example.com, which receives requests from the frontend. However, when I try to log the client IP address in the API, I only see the IP address of example.com (the Vercel server) instead of the actual client IP address.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Reading req.headers['x-forwarded-for']: I added middleware on my API
to log this header, but it always seems to contain the Vercel server
IP.


Are you reading the first IP of the returned array, which should be the client one?
const clientIp = (req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || '').split(',')[0].trim()


I have console logged the output of the hole header and there was only the ip address of vercel visible

If you read the same headers on the frontend app do you see the client IP? So that you could pass it to the APIs together with data?
